# Accessing session variable in template

Tags: twig

I am trying to access stored session in my twig template. But nothing is showing I am not using any frameworks like symphony.

I have used following codes:
menu_profile.html

```
<div class="profile_info">
    <span>Welcome,</span>
    <h2>{{ app.session.get('fname') }}</h2>
  </div>
```

But it is not showing the session variable. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here. How can show session value.

Comment: Which framework are you using? Are you using the `Session Provider`?

Comment: I am not using any frameworks. I have used twig library in my own framework.

Comment: The snippet you provided makes use of a [`session object`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html). If you don't use a framework you are better off with passing the `$_SESSION` variable as global to the template

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: `session_start(); $twig->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);`  / `{{ session.my_variable_name }}`

Comment: In which file do i add $twig->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);? Can i use this code in any file?

Comment: Yes, does not matter. Best place to place is where you initiate `twig` though

Comment: Thanks it is working now. :)